# Ajax request is getting nothing in response - Jquery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made a call to php file, to retrieve some data from database when the document is ready. The sql query select all the data, but i am facing one problem, that is; when i `print_r($est_arr)` it displays me an array. But when i `json_encode($est_arr)` it, i retrieves nothing. Can anyone find the problem. Even when i remove the `[]` inside the `while`, then it `json_encodes()` the last row perfectly like `{"id_estancia":"6","estancia_nombre":"Locales uso industrial"}`, but not the whole array.

**Ajax Request**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"auth.php?getDropDownValues=true"
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
})
```

**PHP Block**

```js
if(isset($_GET["getDropDownValues"])){

 $s_estancia_tab = "SELECT * FROM estancia";

 $est_count = $con->query($s_estancia_tab);

    $est_arr = array ();

 if(mysqli_num_rows($est_count)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($est_count)) {
         $est_arr[] = $row;
        }
 }
 echo json_encode($est_arr);


}
```

**`print_r($est_arr)` result**

```js
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 1
            [estancia_nombre] => Salones y dormitorios
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 2
            [estancia_nombre] => Cocinas y ba�os
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 3
            [estancia_nombre] => Garajes y sotanos
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 4
            [estancia_nombre] => Zonas exteriores
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 5
            [estancia_nombre] => Locales uso comercial
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id_estancia] => 6
            [estancia_nombre] => Locales uso industrial
        )

)
```

Comment: could it possibly be an (very) old php-version with error_reporting off?

Comment: I didnot get you @Jeff

Comment: inspect the request with your console. you should be able to see the return value.
and try to use always and not then.

Comment: what php version do you run? If it's older than 5.2 it doesn't have `json_encode()`. If you then have `error_reporting(0)` you won't see any errors.

Comment: always and then have two completely different purposes. @sheplu

Comment: My php version is 7.1 @Jeff

Comment: That is what i am doing @sheplu

Comment: What you mean by always and then @sheplu i didnt use them

Comment: @KevinB I know, but I know jquery updated a lot of stuff between jquery 2 and 3, and i'm not sure if they changed the behavior of then between both. 

@ NadeemAhmad so you have nothing in your console (network tab) when you call the page? if that's empty and you got no error, then it's your php which doesn't send your data

Comment: They definitely changed the behavior of .then, but for the better. It now more closely follows the behavior of promise.then, but that's entirely irrelevant to this question anyway.

Comment: check the return of [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) after calling `json_encode()`;

Comment: @sheplu in my network the response is OK but the response data is empty I dont know why

Comment: @PatrickQ it says `5`

Comment: That's because of the unrecognized UTF-8 character that's in your array

Comment: so what i have to do now, and what does it mean

Comment: Solved, That was the problem thank you @PatrickQ